# Flutter - google_mobile_ads is it possible to set app tracking transparency using this plugin?

Tags: flutter, google-mobile-ads, apptrackingtransparency

I moved to `google_mobile_ads` and I would like to know if I can also request `App Tracking Transparency` via this plugin or I should use a separate one e.g. [app_tracking_transperancy](https://pub.dev/packages/app_tracking_transparency) to achieve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use the  `app_tracking_transparency` package and explain why you are tracking users' data and how the data is being used in the app.

Comment: ok, so basically, I cannot use `App Tracking Transparency` via this plugin alone, I need another plugin/package :-)

Comment: Yes. Now Apple is strict on this tracking transparency issue. It should be the first thing shown to the user. If you fail to do that, they will definitely  reject your app on the appstore.